# Mutable indexed heterogeneous data structure?

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

Is there a data class or type in Python that matches these criteria?

I am trying to build an object that looks something like this:

- ExperimentData

  - ID 1

    - sample_info_1:  `character string`
    - sample_info_2:  `character string`
    - Dataframe_1: `pandas data frame`
    - Dataframe_2: `pandas data frame`
  - ID 2

    - (etc.)

Right now, I am using a `dict` to hold the object ('ExperimentData'), which contains`namedtuple`'s for each ID. Each of the `namedtuple`'s has a named field for the corresponding data attached to the sample. This allows me to keep all the ID's indexed, and have all of the fields under each ID indexed as well.

However, I need to update and/or replace the entries under each ID during downstream analysis. Since a `tuple` is immutable, this does not seem to be possible.

Is there a better implementation of this?

Comment: You could use a dict of dicts.  Alternatively, if the structure of the inner DataFrames is consistent, you could use a larger DataFrame which subsumes the inner ones into certain columns.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant, but Dataframe1 and Dataframe2 have different structures

Comment: What's more important is whether the structures of all the DataFrame1s (i.e., the one from each ID) are somewhat consistent (and likewise for DataFrame2s).  Can you describe the structure of the inner DataFrames?

Comment: Yes. All Dataframe1's and Dataframe2's share the same structure across all ID's. Each ID has two associated files, which I am reading in to create the df's, but then have to perform downstream manipulation on.

Comment: Then can't you just add two columns to each DataFrame, containing `sample_info_1` and `sample_info_2` (duplicated in each row), and then concat all the DataFrames?  You would then just have two DataFrames that contain all your data.  (You could potentially even join them into one )

Comment: actually your suggestion of using a dict of dicts worked, I had to use a defaultdict of type dict first though. If you submit that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dict of dicts instead of a dict of namedtuples.  Dicts are mutable, so you'll be able to modify the inner dicts.

Given what you said in the comments about the structures of each DataFrame-1 and -2 being comparable, you could also group all of each into one big DataFrame, by adding a column to each DataFrame containing the value of `sample_info_1` repeated across all rows, and likewise for `sample_info_2`.  Then you could concat all the DataFrame-1s into a big one, and likewise for the DataFrame-2s, getting all your data into two DataFrames.  (Depending on the structure of those DataFrames, you could even join them into one.)

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in the comments, I found the `dict` of `dicts` solution to work here, especially after initializing with a `defaultdict` of type `dict`, e.g. `ExperimentData = collections.defaultdict(dict)`. This allows you to later run `ExperimentData[sampleID]['sample_info_1'] = 'my char string'`, etc., from within a loop, updating the entry if it already exists without re initializing the entire dict (and losing previous entries)